# How can I filter API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using the movies API and I want to make it that my page  shows specific movies only.
I want to filter the API to show only latest/new movies that are going to come out. How can I filter API so that I grab only new movies out of all the fetch movies?

Comment: Your question is sparse, I would request to edit it and make it clear.

Comment: What movie API are you talking about? What does your code-snippets look like for what you request help here? Can you also explain what you did already and where you're stuck at the moment?

Comment: I would suggest you to provide more context on the question. Which movies API are you referring to? showing some codes might help.

Answer (score -1):

With as little information as your question has, I'm assuming you're using a public API. The API will have a way to filter options for you (presumably), so you can pass in certain queries to make the returned values more specific.

Or, you can fetch all the movies then write logic on the front-end to filter the array yourself before presenting it to the user.

That's about as detailed as any answer can get on this information.